# Trying to insert into select from two tables that have one to many relations

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have `tbl1`

```
IDa | year | field2 |
----+------+---------
1   | 2015 | bbb    |
2   | 2015 | aaa    |
3   | 2015 | ccc    |
---------------------
```

I'm using `INSERT INTO SELECT` to copy all the data from 2015, but with change in `year` into 2016

```
INSERT INTO tbl1 (year, field2) SELECT '2016', field2 from tbl1 WHERE year = '2015'
```

and return the data like this

```
IDa | year | field2 |
----+------+---------
1   | 2015 | bbb    |
2   | 2015 | aaa    |
3   | 2015 | ccc    |
4   | 2016 | bbb    |
5   | 2016 | aaa    |
6   | 2016 | ccc    |
---------------------
```

Now, I have another table `tbl2` that have a foreign key to `IDa` in `tbl1`, which the relations is one to many like this

```
IDb | year | IDa | field3 |
----+------+-----+---------
1   | 2015 | 1   | ddd    |
2   | 2015 | 1   | eee    |
3   | 2015 | 2   | fff    |
4   | 2015 | 3   | ggg    |
5   | 2015 | 3   | hhh    |
6   | 2015 | 3   | iii    |
---------------------------
```

And now, with `INSERT INTO SELECT` I also want to copy data from `tbl2` in `year` 2015 and change it to 2016, but with `IDa` in `year` 2016

I've tried this

```
INSERT INTO tbl2 (year, IDa, field3)
    SELECT year, (SELECT IDa FROM tbl1 WHERE year = '2016'), field3
    FROM tbl2
    WHERE year = '2015'
```

But this query getting error because one field return multiple value at the time.

So, how to make the right query for this? I want the result is like this

```
IDb | year | IDa | field3 |
----+------+-----+---------
1   | 2015 | 1   | ddd    |
2   | 2015 | 1   | eee    |
3   | 2015 | 2   | fff    |
4   | 2015 | 3   | ggg    |
5   | 2015 | 3   | hhh    |
6   | 2015 | 3   | iii    |
7   | 2016 | 4   | ddd    |
8   | 2016 | 4   | eee    |
9   | 2016 | 5   | fff    |
10  | 2016 | 6   | ggg    |
11  | 2016 | 6   | hhh    |
12  | 2016 | 6   | iii    |
---------------------------
```

Is it possible?

I'm appreciate all the answers, thanks for help.

Comment: Do you store years as character?

Comment: Use a temporary column in tbl1 to store the original primary key. Otherwise you lose that information while copying the data.

Comment: @jarlh no, its int

Comment: @PaulSpiegel how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it stands your sub query doesn't return the `IDa` for one row, but all of the values for the whole year.  *(This is a problem because you can't put all those values in one field in one row.)*

To fix your exact syntax you need to "correlate" the sub query against the table you're reading from, so that you get only one result per row, for your IDa lookup...

Unfortunately, in your case, that gets very messy.  You need to look up what the original `IDa` was in table1, then look for the matching row in the same table but for the next year...

```
INSERT INTO
    tbl2 (
        year,
        IDa,
        field3
    )
SELECT
    year + 1,
    (SELECT IDa
       FROM tbl1
      WHERE year   = tbl2.year + 1
        AND field2 = (SELECT field2
                        FROM tbl1
                       WHERE IDa = tbl2.IDa
                     )
    ),
    field3
FROM
    tbl2
WHERE
    year = '2015'
```

That said, there is a simpler way, using joins...

```
INSERT INTO
    tbl2 (
        year,
        IDa,
        field3
    )
SELECT
    newer.year,
    newer.IDa,
    tbl2.field3
FROM
    tbl2
INNER JOIN
    tbl1   older
       ON  older.IDa    = tbl2.IDa
INNER JOIN
    tbl1   newer
       ON  newer.year   = older.year + 1
       AND newer.field2 = older.field2
WHERE
    tbl2.year = 2015
```

***EDIT***

If `field2` doesn't exist, you have the problem of not knowing which `IDa` to pick in each case.

That leaves two options, as I see it:
- Use the approach from @PaulSpiegel
- Manually introduce a proxy

Personally, this is sounding more and more convoluted, and a basic redesign sounds like it's going to be beneficial.

If you're unable to re-design or use the method from @PaulSpiegel, there is an option...

```
INSERT INTO
    tbl2 (
        year,
        IDa,
        field3
    )
WITH
   ordered_tbl1
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY year ORDER BY year)   AS ordinal,
        tbl1.*
    FROM
        tbl1
)
SELECT
    newer.year,
    newer.IDa,
    tbl2.field3
FROM
    tbl2
INNER JOIN
    ordered_tbl1    older
       ON  older.IDa     = tbl2.IDa
INNER JOIN
    ordered_tbl1    newer
       ON  newer.year    = older.year + 1
       AND newer.ordinal = older.ordinal
WHERE
    tbl2.year = 2015
```

This assumes the only fields in `tbl1` are `year` and `IDa`.  If you have other fields in `tbl1` then they should be included in the `ROW_NUMBER()`'s `ORDER BY` clause, to ensure that the rows appear in the same order in both years.

If this doesn't make sense to you, then you probably shouldn't use it.  Instead re-design or use @PaulSpiegel's approach.

Comment: `tbl1.IDa` is it the newer one, or the the older?

Comment: @JTR - Sorry, typo, but I'd have hoped you realised that it's the `newer` one, as that's the whole point of what you asked for ;)  *(Sorry, early and Trump news is making me grouchy and sarcastic.)*

Comment: If we do not see the `field2`, is it still possible to get it right?

Comment: @JTR - What do you mean `do not see the field2`?

Comment: @MatBailie I mean, if there's no field2

Comment: @JTR Then you're probably doing something badly wrong.  It's still possible, if you understand what my edit is suggesting.  But it's giving a really bad code smell; you shouldn't need to jump through these hoops, it indicates your design is missing something or flawed in some other way.  Without more information on your actual use case it's hard to advise further, but consider the difficulty here as an indication that you're taken the wrong path somewhere.

Comment: I think I change this is as the correct answer, however adding a column in my query also work, but I think this one is better for me, Thank you MatBailie :)

Answer (score 2):

Add column `oIDa` (original ID) to `tbl1`.

```
ALTER TABLE tbl1 ADD oIDa INT;
```

Copy data with the original ID, so you can use it later.

```
INSERT INTO tbl1 (year, field2, oIDa) SELECT '2016', field2, IDa from tbl1 WHERE year = '2015';
```

Now you have a column, that you can join on, to find the new generated `IDa` value:

```
INSERT INTO tbl2 (year, IDa, field3)
    SELECT year, tbl1.IDa, tbl2.field3
    FROM tbl2
    JOIN tbl1 ON tbl1.oIDa = tbl2.IDa
    WHERE tbl2.year = 2015;
```

Now you can remove the new column:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl1 DROP COLUMN oIDa;
```

Comment: uumm... I'm sorry but, what is `INT  UNSIGNED` are again?

Comment: `INT UNSIGNED` means only positive integers (from 0 to 4,294,967,295). But you can just take the same data type as you use for `IDa`.

Comment: Sorry, just realized the sql-server tag. I've adjusted the code.

Comment: Ooh... it's work, sorry I've just tested, and yes, this is work. Thank you sir :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't 100% understand your data - so I'm not sure if Field2 and Field3 will always be the same for each year. If it is then this should work:

```
INSERT INTO tbl2 (year, IDa, field3)
SELECT c.Year,
       c.Ida,
       a.field3
  FROM tbl2 a
       INNER JOIN tbl1 b
               ON a.IDa = b.Ida
       INNER JOIN tbl1 c
               ON field2 = field2
              AND c.year = 2016
 WHERE a.year = '2015';
```

Comment: yes, `field2` and `field3` in the same order each year

Comment: @JTR Change the line `ON field2 = field2` to `ON c.field2 = b.field2`   *(And then also change the aliases from `a`, `b` and `c` so something much more readable ;) )*